# How serious is the following Memory leak shown by Valgrind

Tags: c, linux, valgrind

After writing thousands of lines of code I use valgrind and am horrified to see the amount of errors. Was just using GDB before. Most of my errors are with string functions. I post a portion. I understand the error is happening because strlen does not count the trailing NULL whereas strcpy adds it. How serious is it? Do I really need to fix them? I can fix it but worry if that may lead to more errors as my code did not not keep that in mind when I as wriitng it.

Does the strcpy copy the trailing NULL even if the is no space reserved for it?

```
t.write_length = (strlen("NA\n");/*Line number 116*/
t.data = malloc(strlen("NA\n");/*117*/
strcpy(t.data,"NA\n");/*118*/
```

Valgrind:

```
==3287== Invalid write of size 1
==3287==    at 0x400764E: memcpy (mc_replace_strmem.c:497)
==3287==    by 0x804A714: log_txn_commit (Log_manager.c:118)
==3287==    by 0x8049D3C: on_txn_commit (TxFS_manager.c:85)
==3287==    by 0x804939E: handler (Reader.c:139)
==3287==    by 0xBF5F18: start_thread (in /lib/libpthread-2.12.90.so)
==3287==    by 0xB37A2D: clone (in /lib/libc-2.12.90.so)
==3287==  Address 0x403282b is 0 bytes after a block of size 3 alloc'd
==3287==    at 0x4005BDC: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:195)
==3287==    by 0x804A6F5: log_txn_commit (Log_manager.c:117)
==3287==    by 0x8049D3C: on_txn_commit (TxFS_manager.c:85)
==3287==    by 0x804939E: handler (Reader.c:139)
==3287==    by 0xBF5F18: start_thread (in /lib/libpthread-2.12.90.so)
==3287==    by 0xB37A2D: clone (in /lib/libc-2.12.90.so)
```

Comment: Every memory leak is serious, son.

Comment: BTW your testcase does not compile, because you missed out a `)`. This indicates that you did not test the code you gave us. This is very important.

Comment: That is not a "memory leak". Your code is overwriting memory that is not allocated to you, and is a serious problem. Probably more serious than *any* memory leak.

Comment: This is not a `memory leak`, this is a `invalid write`.   You can ignore leaks, but never overlook invalid write.

Comment: It should also be noted that `strlen` is an O(N) operation, not an O(1) one. Calling it twice on the same string is wasteful, especially since I suspect your real code doesn't always use a string literal as short as `"NA\n"`.

Comment: The missing ( is a typing error here. Am sorry. the code is tested.

Comment: @Tomalak: Every memory leak is serious, but plenty of "leaks" detected by valgrind are not leaks (e.g. `int main() { malloc(1); }`) while valgrind fails to find plenty of leaks (e.g. all the ones in Firefox) due to there being code paths to free the memory at exit time but no way to free it until then, even though it will never be used again...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is a serious memory overwrite problem. Your code should be

```
t.write_length = strlen("NA\n");/*Line number 116*/
t.data = malloc(t.write_length + 1);
strcpy(t.data,"NA\n");
```

and needs fixing for sure.  `strcpy()` will append the termininating `'\0'` which there isn't room for.

> To avoid overflows, the size of the array pointed by destination shall
>   be long enough to contain the same C string as source (including the
>   terminating null character), and should not overlap in memory with
>   source.

Always take Valgrind's advice seriously!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you always need to `malloc(strlen(str) + 1)` bytes for a string (for that pesky null terminator). Or the easier way would be using `strdup`.

Comment: OP is pre-calculating (and storing) the `strlen` already. Calling `strdup` would recalculate that length and be inefficient. (Of course, the OP's code does the same thing, but still.)

Comment: That's kind of what I was getting at, all that code is doing is copying a string which `strdup` makes a tad easier. And honestly if strlen accidentally gets invoked twice but the code is a tad more readable, I'd call it even (unless it's an embedded system, of course).

Comment: If this piece of code gets called a lot, not really. It's already got two O(N) operations, plus a `malloc`. No need for it to be slower than it has to be.

Comment: @Chris: Copying is `O(n)` anyway, so *in principle*, `strdup` could have a special agreement with `malloc` whereby it could get a large block to begin with and return all but the end of it to the system when done. (Of course if the string ended up being really large it would have to `realloc` and copy it again. :-P)

Comment: @R.. - That's an interesting thought. Do any `strdup` implementations do this in practice?

Comment: I doubt so. Actually I think it's probably a pretty bad idea; any situation where you take more memory than you need then shrink it down in place (note you could just do this with `realloc` on most implementations anyway) is going to fragment memory much worse than allocating the right amount to begin with. It was more just a random musing.

Answer (score 5):

You always want to fix errors reported by Valgrind. Invalid writes lead to unexpected behavior, which is by definition not what your program should do. Depending on how your program is laid out in memory, you could be overwriting other important variables, or not fully writing what you expect.

If fixing this leads to more errors in your code, that means that other parts of your code are in error, not Valgrind's report. You should fix this bug, and if that leads to further errors being reported, you fix those, too. Ignore invalid read / write errors at your own peril.

Answer (score 2):

Potentially quite serious, and you should fix it.  Consider using either `strdup()` if you need the trailing null or `memcpy()` if you don't need the trailing null.

Comment: Although it's incorrect, I don't think the code will necessarily cause the program to fail.  For example in glibc the smallest mallocable size is 16 bytes.